# Countdown Timer...Don't know where to start

Tags: python

I am very very ***new*** to python and  I am trying to make a **simple timer** app with it.
So if I input a number, like 30, the code should start counting down and output

```
>>> 30
>>> 29
>>> 28
>>> 27
```

and so on..

I am trying to get some logic into my brain. I was trying to do this since to days with same code in different places.

```
import time

x = input("seconds to blast off: ")
for z in range(x):
    timer.sleep(x)
print("blast off")
```

This is all I have written and I am stuck here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import time

sec = int(input('No. of seconds: '))
print(sec)

for s in range(sec):
    sec = int(sec) - 1
    time.sleep(1)
    if sec == 0:
        print("Blast Off")
    else:
        print(str(sec))
```

You got quite close to the solution.
timer.sleep() takes in the number of seconds.
Although, you could have found such answers on the web.

Comment: Thank you very much. You solution worked very well. Sorry, next time onwards I will do more research before posting a question.

Comment: This answer doesn't really address the issues OP had, more just pasting an answer

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things here that need a little work.

First, `input` will always returns a string, so `x` is also a string. So if the user were to input '30', you would run `for z in range('30'):` which will error. Instead, you should cast `x` to an int with `int(x)`.

Next, it's `time.sleep`, not `timer.sleep`

The way I'd implement the counter part personally would be to keep track of the start time, then calculate the end time. Then, find the difference between the time in the iteration and the end time and loop while that is greater than 0. It might look like this:

```py
import time

x = int(input('Number of seconds: '))

end = time.time() + x

while end - time.time() > 0:
    print(round(end - time.time()))
    time.sleep(1)
```